# How to fix eval () error PHP

Tags: php, system, eval

I have an Array something like this.

```
ARRAY[0][DATAROOTNEW.PROPIEDADES.OPERACION][0]
ARRAY[0][DATAROOTNEW.PROPIEDADES.HABITACIONES][0]
ARRAY[0][DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.BANO][0]
ARRAY[0][DATAROOT.PROPIEDADES.TITULO][0]
```

And I have a PHP code that checks if the string provided is a PHP script and using eval() it executes. The code is as follows

```
$result='';
    $is_php=false;
    $pos=strpos($item,'PHP:');
    if($pos===0){
        $is_php=true;
        $code=str_replace('PHP:','',$item);
        $pos=strpos($code,$base_name_feed);
        if($pos>=0){
            foreach($keys as $k){
             $code=str_replace('['.$k.']','$this->ARRAY['.$current_item.']["'.$k.'"][0]',$code);
            }
        }
    }
    if($is_php){
                echo '<p>'.$code.'</p>';
                eval($code);
    }
```

The string that I provide to the code is something like this

```
if([DATAROOTNEW.PROPIEDADES.HABITACIONES] >=1 or [DATAROOTNEW.PROPIEDADES.BANOS]>=1) { if($this->IdCategoria=='') $this->setIdCategoria(); $result="cat".$this->IdCategoria."_1[;;]Detail_Rooms[;;]DOUBLE[;;]".[DATAROOTNEW.PROPIEDADES.HABITACIONES]."[;;]0[;;;]cat".$this->IdCategoria."_2[;;]Detail_Bathrooms[;;]DOUBLE[;;]".[DATAROOTNEW.PROPIEDADES.BANOS]."[;;]0"; } else $result='';
```

So my code replaces all the string that matches with the array . and make it as a valid code .

```
$code=str_replace('['.$k.']','$this->ARRAY['.$current_item.']["'.$k.'"][0]',$code);
```

The problem is if the key doesnot exist in the Array the code becomes invalid because the replace statement will not be effective.

My question is how should I validate this so that `Eval()` does not executes ?

Comment: Couldn't you check if the array item [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)?

Comment: Please, forget that something like `eval` exists.

Comment: @panther can you tell me what should I use in place of eval() also How I can fix my problem

Comment: The fact that you need `eval()` is usually a sign that something has gone horribly wrong in the design phase. That solution looks like a nightmare to maintain. If I encountered that kind of code in a project I'd probably suggest a complete refactoring.